# Trouble getting buttons to show interactive content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rv18kd6c/31/

I am having trouble trying to get the other 3 buttons to show, the same content as the 'recent' button. Can someone give me some pointers please?
The other three buttons need to also show the side bar and tables interacting in the same way as they do on the 'recent' button.
Thanks in advance :)

Below is all the code that has been written so far. The JQuery is to show and hide the content.

The javascript changes which tables are being shown, I think i need 3 more javascript queries but i am struggling to make it work.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .button-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .button-wrapper a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px
  }

  .content h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2em;
  }

  .top-button {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #00622b;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5rem;
    margin: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12;
    -moz-border-radius: 12;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  .top-button a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }

  table {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
  }

  table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #98FB98;
  }

  table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: mediumseagreen;
  }

  table th {
    background-color: #98FB98;
    color: #00622b;
  }

  * {
    box-sizing: border-box
  }

  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  /* Style the tab */

  .tab {
    float: left;
    border: none;
    background-color: #00622b;
    width: 30%;
  }

  /* Style the buttons inside the tab */

  .tab button {
    display: block;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: #ffffff80;
    padding: 22px 16px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 2vw;
  }

  /* Change background color of buttons on hover */

  .tab button:hover {
    color: #ffffffbf;
  }

  /* Create an active/current "tab button" class */

  .tab button.active {
    background-color: #00622b;
    color: #fff;
  }

  /* Style the tab content */

  .tabcontent {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 12px;
    width: 70%;
    border-left: none;
  }

</style>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <a class="flip top-button" href="#first-div" target="" data-toggle="">Recent</a>
    <a class="flip top-button" href="#second-div" target="" data-toggle="">Top</a>
    <a class="flip top-button" href="#third-div" target="" data-toggle="">Standard</a>
    <a class="flip top-button" href="#fourth-div" target="" data-toggle="">Rotten</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content" id="first-div">
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openRating(event, 'Value')" id="defaultOpen">Value for Money</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openRating(event, 'Time')">Time Taken</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openRating(event, 'Quality')">Quality of Work</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openRating(event, 'Average')">Average Rating</button>
    </div>

    <div id="Value" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>
        Recent
      </h3>
      <table id="bottom5">

        <tr>
          <th>Value for Money</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div id="Time" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>
        Recent
      </h3>
      <table id="bottom5">

        <tr>
          <th>Time Taken</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div id="Quality" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>
        Recent
      </h3>
      <table id="bottom5">

        <tr>
          <th>Quality of Work</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div id="Average" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>
        Recent
      </h3>
      <table id="bottom5">

        <tr>
          <th>Average Rating</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="content" id="second-div" style="display:none">
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="third-div" style="display:none">
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="fourth-div" style="display:none">
  </div>

  <script>
    function openRating(evt, ratingName) {
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      document.getElementById(ratingName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }

    // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

    // only show one panel at a time
    jQuery(".flip").on("click", function(e) {
      var target = jQuery(this).attr("href");
      jQuery(target).slideToggle("fast");
      jQuery(".content").not(target).hide();
      e.preventDefault();
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want here : the last 3 buttons woks but they open some empty divs (<div class="content" id="second-div" style="display:none"></div>) what do you expect them to do ?

Comment: I want the other buttons to display the same results as the 'recent' button. The divs are empty because when they aren't it breaks the code at the moment and doesn't demonstrate how i want it to look.

Comment: Like @Neil said, there is no content in the other divs. If you want the same content to be displayed as recent, copy and paste the innerHTML into the other 3 divs.

Comment: I know the other divs are empty. When they are full of the same information as the first div is they don't display the same information, hence the post.

Comment: just to be sure, why would you want **4 buttons for the same thing** ? do you want to change them separately later ? i tried putting text in the 2 3 4 divs, and they all work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rv18kd6c/36/ this is what it looks like when it is copy and pasted into the other divs...

Comment: i saw, the issue is with your javascript and multiple "defaultOpen" i'm posting you a way around ;)

Comment: notice how the table isn't showing, on 'top', 'standard' or 'rotten'.

Comment: nice one neil!!

Comment: one simple question : you used ids for rating names, does that mean that on the left the choices are going to be different if you change the tab, or can they be the same ?

Comment: Ultimately the tables are going to be populated from a database. So the tables will all contain different information. I have simply copy and pasted that table for quickness.

Answer (score 1):

the issue here is that on page load you launch this :

```
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

but when you have multiple defaultOpen IDs only the first one is clicked (that is not a problem since only the first one is visible), then when you click another tab, you don't refresh witch new defaultOpen to choose. that is how you do it :

```
// only show one panel at a time
jQuery(".flip").on("click", function(e) {
  var target = jQuery(this).attr("href");
  jQuery(target).slideToggle("fast");
  jQuery(".content").not(target).hide();
  jQuery(target).find("#defaultOpen")[0].click();//here i find the default open IN the newly active tab
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

but this will visually do nothing because your **onclick="openRating(event, 'Value')"** will only open the first **#Value"** div it finds :
from there two solutions:

**1** You never use twice the same id for categories on the left (notice ids **Valuetab2** instead of value for example)

```
<div class="content" id="second-div" style="display:none">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openRating(event, 'Valuetab2')" id="defaultOpen">Value for Money</button><!--changed here -->
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="Valuetab2" class="tabcontent"><!--changed here -->
    ...
```

or **2** you use classes for categories and adapt a little your code so it opens every catagory with the same class

```
<div class="content" id="second-div" style="display:none">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openRating(event, 'Value')" id="defaultOpen">Value for Money</button>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="Value tabcontent"> <!--changed here -->
```

and replace `document.getElementById(ratingName).style.display = "block";`
by `$("."+ratingName).css('display','block');` to display all categories with that same class (they will all be displayed, but inside invisible tabs for the other)

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for the explanation, do you have a visual representation this working?

Comment: @Sutters92 oh forgot the jQuery(target).find("#defaultOpen")[0].click(); , here it is :https://jsfiddle.net/rv18kd6c/90/